# Reduce mesh size of data set for Surface pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I want to reduce the amount of sample points latex uses for creating a pgf surface plot. My data file currently has a mesh of (41x401) points. I am looking for a way to implement the (each nth point=?) statement to reduce the mesh size to for example (41X41). I am using the following code to make a surface plot of the fairly large data set:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=9cm,width=12cm]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp] table[x index=0, y index=1, z index=2] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am compiling this with LuaLaTex due to the the main memory size error I get when I compile the plot with pdfLaTex.

data file can be downloaded here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oa0vgtvgx6znqmd/data.dat?dl=0

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Let's hope you *never* move the downloadable data from your Dropbox, otherwise it would make this post somewhat useless later down the road... My suggestion would be to reduce the sample size from your 16K+ points to something that is manageable and include it in your post.